# Dynamically change dynamic selector values in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table structure like this

```
  <tr>
    <td class="pg4 monthlyP">Value1</td>
    <td class="pg4 monthlyP">Value2</td>
    <td class="pg4 monthlyP">Value3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I am fetching some values from an api (fetchApi) and storing those in `v11, v12, v21, v22, v31, v32`
What I want to achieve is

#1. to change the table td structure dynamically to

```
<td class="pg4 monthlyP">
    <span class="new">$<span id="arm5yr11">1,337.86</span> / $<span id="arm5yr12">1,360.28</span></span>
   </td>
<td class="pg4 monthlyP">
    <span class="new">$<span id="arm5yr21">1,338.86</span> / $<span id="arm5yr22">1,361.28</span></span>
   </td>
<td class="pg4 monthlyP">
    <span class="new">$<span id="arm5yr31">1,339.86</span> / $<span id="arm5yr32">1,362.28</span></span>
   </td>
```

I am doing this

```
    jQuery('.pg4.monthlyP:eq(1)').html('<span class="twoRatesARM">$<span id="arm5yr11">1,337.86</span> / $<span id="arm5yr12">1,360.28</span></span>');
    jQuery('.pg4.monthlyP:eq(2)').html('<span class="twoRatesARM">$<span id="arm5yr21">1,338.86</span> / $<span id="arm5yr22">1,361.28</span></span>');
    jQuery('.pg4.monthlyP:eq(3)').html('<span class="twoRatesARM">$<span id="arm5yr31">1,339.86</span> / $<span id="arm5yr32">1,362.28</span></span>');
```

#2. to fill the api values by targetting respective span ids like this

```
    document.getElementById("arm5yr11").innerHTML = v11;
    document.getElementById("arm5yr12").innerHTML = v12;
    document.getElementById("arm5yr21").innerHTML = v21;
    document.getElementById("arm5yr22").innerHTML = v22;
    document.getElementById("arm5yr31").innerHTML = v31;
    document.getElementById("arm5yr32").innerHTML = v32;
```

Problem is #2 is not working.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: v11.toFixed is not a function` I am formatting the variable like this `v11.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");`

Comment: Can you console.log(v11) before the error?

Comment: i think i got the mistake. I already formatted the variable after promise response inside fetch API. Hence, I got this error `toFixed is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can use is to put the API values in an array then you can use the `.html(Function)` method to create all the content on the fly in a single step, like so:

```
//Let's say
const v11 = 1, v12 = 2, v21 = 3, v22 = 4, v31 = 5, v32 = 6;

//We can put these values in an array:
const arr = [v11, v12, v21, v22, v31, v32];

//And create the span elements and populate them as follows:
$('td.pg4.monthlyP')
.html(i => `<span class="new">$<span>${arr[2*i]}</span> / $<span>${arr[2*i+1]}</span></span>`);
```

```js
//Let's say
const v11 = 1, v12 = 2, v21 = 3, v22 = 4, v31 = 5, v32 = 6;

//We can put these values in an array:
const arr = [v11, v12, v21, v22, v31, v32];

//And create the span elements and populate them as follows:
$('td.pg4.monthlyP')
.html(i => `<span class="new">$<span>${arr[2*i]}</span> / $<span>${arr[2*i+1]}</span></span>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="pg4 monthlyP">Value1</td>
    <td class="pg4 monthlyP">Value2</td>
    <td class="pg4 monthlyP">Value3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```